# How to format traceback objects in Python

Tags: python, object, format, traceback

I have a traceback object that I want to show in the nice format I get when calling `traceback.format_exc()`.

Is there a builtin function for this? Or a few lines of code?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`format_exc()` is really just

```py
etype, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
return ''.join(format_exception(etype, value, tb, limit))
```

So if you have the exception type, value, and traceback ready, it should be easy. If you have just the exception, notice that `format_exception()` is essentially:

```py
a_list = ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n']
a_list = a_list + format_tb(tb, limit)
```

where `limit` defaults to `None`.

Comment: I think I'm the only one that doesn't understand this answer... This answer doesn't say where to import `format_tb`, and is using the built in `list` as a variable. And I still don't understand how to print the traceback.

Comment: @NicScozzaro - I update the answer so that it doesn't use `list`. Also `format_tb()` is part of the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module. You can simply `from traceback import format_tb` and then use it.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried [traceback.print_tb](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_tb) or [traceback.format_tb](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_tb)?

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't find this anywhere, so I'm posting it here for future people and my future self.

```
try:
  raise Exception('Not an Exception')
except Exception as err:
  msg = "".join(traceback.format_exception(type(err), err, err.__traceback__))
  print(msg)
```

This takes your exception and provides a string formatted identically to python's default exception printer/`print_tb`

Answer (score 4):

`traceback` docs give [few examples](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples) and [whole set of functions](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) for formatting traceback objects.

Answer (score -1):

See also [`traceback.print_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)