# AttributeError: 'traceback' object has no attribute 'format_exception'

Tags: python, traceback

Here is my code, simplified to illustrate the problem:

```
import sys
def my_excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print(exc_traceback.format_exception())
sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
x = 5/0
```

Python hits another exception while handling the ZeroDivisionError, hence the title of this post.

[Looking at my debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZKhq.png), it's certainly a traceback object. It has four attributes:

- tb_frame: frame
- tb_lasti: int
- tb_lineno: int
- tb_next: traceback

but no methods. Why?

edit:

Reading the [traceback module python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception), I had the misconception that I was reading the traceback object python docs.

[how to format traceback objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378889/how-to-format-traceback-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting a traceback *object* confused with the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) *package*, which contains a [`format_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) function.

```
import sys
import traceback
def my_excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
x = 5/0
```

Comment: Or just `traceback.format_exception(exc_value)`, starting from python 3.10.